# Time to be LESS organised

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[organization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/organization) is a pretty big meta-tag.

It's uses include,

- Organisation charts
- Sorting data
- Windows Explorer functionality
- Email organisation

and many more.

Should we burn it?

Comment: Yes, we should! :]

Comment: I came here thinking you were gonna talk about `LESS`, the CSS preprocessor!

Comment: I came here thinking you were gonna talk about `more`.  I'm pretty disappointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[organization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/organization) cleanup completed.