# Cleanup up [organization] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Most of the 98 questions with the undefined [organization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/organization) tag refer to providing structure, and that is probably the appropriate usage.  There are some exceptions that should be retagged.  A number refer to a specific type of chart and those should be retagged with the existing [chart](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chart) tag.  At least one refers to doing something in a business environment.  I have no idea what to do with that.  A placeholder definition should be created indicating that the intended meaning relates to providing structure.

Comment: Great minds think alike :) https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8539/time-to-be-less-organised